# Hermaphrodites (born with both sets of genitalia): Do surgeons HAVE to perform surgery? How soon? Decision basis for which genitalia to keep?

Tags: medical-ethics, gender-sex-identity

According to research by [Organization Intersex International](http://oii-usa.org/2563/how-common-is-intersex-in-humans/), **hermaphrodites** (born with both male and female genitalia) "make up **1 in 2000**, or **.05%**." Babies born as hermaphrodites happen more than the general public realizes or history acknowledges... so I seek for a better medical understanding of these individuals.

*What typically happens to these babies?*

1. Is a **surgery necessary for all hermaphrodites?** Like is it physically possible for them to live full-lives with both genitalia?
2. Do the **doctors or the parents decide** what **sex** the **child** will be? If so, on what **basis** is the **gender/sex** of the baby **determined** prior to the **surgery** removing the "extra" genitalia? *Do they base it off of which genitalia is more developed?*
3. At what **age** of the infant do they perform these surgeries?
4. Are the **transgender and bisexual**  (LGBTQ) **rates** of those born as hermaphrodites the same/lower/more than others born with one set of genitalia?
   Are the **surgeries reversible?** Like if a person later on felt like the doctors/parents chose a gender that they don't identify with...

*My questions are sincere and I apologize for my ignorance concerning hermaphrodites (which is why I try to seek answers) or if I lack the skills to phrase my questions in a proper manner. I know each person is different and complex, I am just wondering about what generally happens and the impact it has on their future. I apologize if I may offend anyone with my questions. Please forgive me if I do.*

Comment: What have you learned so far with your own searching/research?

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD, thanks. I have revised my question by including the statistic on how common it is (see above) -- so that the questions focus on the larger picture.

Comment: These are excellent questions. I am looking forward to these answers. I, too, respectfully wish to have an increased understanding, but never knew of a safe place where to ask these questions.

Comment: As for question #1, since hermaphrodites have been known throughout history, I'd say it's safe to say they can live full lives with both genitalia.